# How to add a transparent Bootstrap Navbar to a Fullpage.js site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js

I want to add a transparent Bootstrap Navbar to a page which use fullpage.js. I want to achieve something like [this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page2), so that the navbar stays on top of the page but doesn't `push` the website contents down. How can I do this? I tried the code below but it doesn't work. I tried looking for solutions online but I couldn't find one. Here is some sample code. As you can see the navbar is not even displaying.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.css" integrity="sha512-TD/aL30dNLN0VaHVoh9voFlNi7ZuWQYtV4bkIJv2ulZ8mEEkZJ7IyGvDthMKvIUwzLmPONnjQlAi55HTERVXpw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/master.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="fullpage">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-transparent" id="myMenu">
            <!-- Brand -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    
            <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
                style="border: none;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <div class="container-fluid">

            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

    <script>
        new fullpage('#fullpage', {
            //options here
            menu: '#myMenu',
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollHorizontally: true,
            navigation: true,
        });

        //methods
        fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Building your own should be easy, If you want help with your code. try and post a runnable demo here so we can check the problem with your code and try and find the solution.

Comment: Try putting the `<nav class="navbar">` *OUTSIDE* (like above it, not nested inside it) of the `<div id="fullpage">`

Comment: @zgood I tried it, but then its pushing the content down and its becoming a mess. I wand to achieve the exact effect as in the the demo i linked above

Comment: @xJwG Have you looked at the options for this plugin [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options)? There is an option called "menu" about setting up a menu to work with the plugin, have you tried that?

Comment: @xJwG Set the `.navbar` outside the `#fullpage` and make sure the navbar is position "fixed". Look at the Bootstrap navbar docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement) .... you need to add the class "fixed-top". See my demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5j208Lz4/)

Comment: @zgood Thats not what im looking to do. I want the contents of "section" div to overflow with the Navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a fix myself. I edited the css of the "navbar" class so instead of a relative position its position is fixed and now it works just as i wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles to the navbar

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.css" integrity="sha512-TD/aL30dNLN0VaHVoh9voFlNi7ZuWQYtV4bkIJv2ulZ8mEEkZJ7IyGvDthMKvIUwzLmPONnjQlAi55HTERVXpw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js"></script>
      <link href="css/master.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   </head>
   <body>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-transparent" id="myMenu">
            <!-- Brand -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
               style="border: none;">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
               <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About us</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
      <div id="fullpage">

         <div class="section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         new fullpage('#fullpage', {
             //options here
             menu: '#myMenu',
             autoScrolling: true,
             scrollHorizontally: true,
             navigation: true,
         });
         
         //methods
         fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
      </script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know how to make the navbar transparent. Your answer has nothing to do with my question, but thanks for the contribution.

Comment: My bad , please post a runnable demo so you can receive help easier

Comment: Here is the demo on [CodePen] (https://codepen.io/kuba-gawroski/pen/NWjeErm)

Comment: check my edited answer seems to be working fine for me just by moving the nav above your content div

Comment: Its not what I'm looking for. As you can see, once you open the Navmenu, the contents of the page are "pushed". Same would apply for eg. with a background image on the whole page. I want the contents of the "section" part to overflow with the navbar.